# Stream screen contents over network

Tags: tv, screen-sharing

At work, we are thinking of getting a TV for presentation/showing things. I had the idea that we could connect a PC, to stream our screens (wirelessly) through it, to the TV (like inverse screen sharing). Is this possible?

Both Windows and Mac users would need to share their screen.

```
Screen sharer PC  --[wifi]-->  PC  --[HDMI]-->  TV
```

Comment: About a year ago, me and a friend started to write software that could do just that, It was an embedded Linux device with HDMI out. Wish we would of finished it now!!!

Comment: I googled for "wireless OR 802.11 PC screen HDMI" and got some results that looked relevant.

Comment: Steve> That's cool, how far have you come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by:

1. Run a VNC viewer in [listen mode](http://wfefww.realvnc.com/pipermail/vnc-list/2005-June/051089.html) on PC connected to TV.
2. Run a VNC server on Screen sharer PC, connecting it to the listen mode viewer.

There are several VNC software options for Mac ([Chicken of the VNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/), [JollyFastVNC](http://www.jinx.de/JollysFastVNC.html)) and Windows ([TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/), [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/)).

Comment: You mean I could actually make the server connect to the client?

Comment: Yes, that's what listen mode is for. [Here's](http://tinyapps.org/docs/vnc/) a decent-looking tutorial, in the context of remote support.